# Loading Specific Content from one page into another Page using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I'm new to Ajax and was told need to use it for what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Here is the website... http://modocom.ca/gillons

If you scroll down up will see a section called Find an Office with drop down menu in it. What I need is for when someone click on for example Emo in the dropdown menu the location info from.... http://modocom.ca/gillons/emo goes under the dropdown and so on for each location in the dropdown and also when your on the Emo page for example you click on the dropdown menu and can choose different location and get new info as well for selected location.

Hope that makes sense and hopefully someone could give me a hand.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't request code without at least trying it yourself.

Comment: I honestly have no clue what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not going to write code as it looks as though you haven't actually tried anything yourself yet.

However, the sequence of events, one version of them anyway, might look like this.

Using jQuery, put a change event on your dropdown.

When the event triggers, and this depends on your backend as you have not spcified APS.Net, MNV, Java etc, you need to post back to a code file of some sort and pass in the value within the dropdown.

From there, in your c#, java, pythod, whatever, code, take that value, generate some HTML and return that HTML to the client.

At the client, you accept the HTML and fill say a DIV with the returned HTML.

If you are using MVC, you can return a PartialView which is a better design.

Comment: Thank you I have tried something if you look at my dropdown when you click on something it doesn't load in data I have before my closing body tags some JavaScript and Ajax script

Comment: Post your code.  Difficult to trouble shoot something when you don't know what that something is.  :)

Comment: Ok will post code when I get home should I post the whole pages code or just area I need help with.

Comment: As little as possible.  Maybe write a POC page and post the JS and the code behind just to do with the issue.

Comment: You may want to delete this message and do another one as it will become stale and you are already getting down voted.

Comment: @user3059280 I'd advise against the above suggestion, as it would contribute to a question ban and/or get closed as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Daedalus, not if he deletes it as i suggested!

Comment: @griegs As far as I'm aware, deleted, downvoted questions contribute to the ban.  Deleting just makes it worse.

Comment: @Daedalus, Catch 22.  If he deletes and re asks he's penalized.  So he doesn't delete it and the question stagnates and no one looks at it.  But if he re-asks then it's a duplicate and he's penalized.  Hmmm, not ideal

Comment: Ill ask new question sorry I'm new here not sure how to display my code.

Comment: @griegs Editing a question usually bumps it up though, so it no longer becomes stale.  He won't get penalized just as long as he doesn't edit it too much.